# Rename a file and move a level up

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I'm trying to write a script that will go through a director structure like:

```
school/admission/english->index.html
```

It should rename index.html to english.html which is it's parent folder and move it a level up  so that the result would be like

```
school/admission/english.html
```

This same process should get repeated for all the files by the name `index.html` in that folder structure. Any help about how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

To find all the index.html files I have:

```
   @echo off
for /r %%i in (index.html) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%i
```

To move .html files one level up:

```
for /r %x in (*.html) do move "%x" "%x"/../..
```

Comment: I'm going to update the script that I have in few sec...hold on

Comment: @ngmiceli I'm stuck on how to rename the files to it's parent folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple native solution that can be run from the command line

```
for /r %F in (index.html) do @for /f "eol=: delims=" %A in ("%F\..") do @if exist "%F" move "%F" "%F\..\..\%~nA%~xF"
```

**EDIT in response to additional question in comment**

I think it best to use a batch script if you want to only process leaf nodes of the folder hierarchy:

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (index.html) do (
  if exist "%%F" (
    set "subFolder="
    for /d %%A in ("%%~dpF\*") do set subFolder=1
    if not defined subFolder for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ("%%F\..") do move "%%F" "%%F\..\..\%%~nA%%~xF"
  )
)
```

Comment: This one works well...Can we add a condition to this so that it only does the process for index.html without sub-folders? I mean only rename and move index.html which does not have any subfolder in it (like only the last ones in the folder hierarchy) ?